# fsockopen is timing out

Tags: php, timeout, fsockopen, whois

i am following a script so i can check domain names in bulk. I have tryed this with just using about 10 domain ideas and it works. But now im trying to run this with thousands of domain ideas but it just loads for a while then goes to 404

here is my function

```
function is_avail($domain) 
{     
    $pieces = explode(".", $domain); 
    $server = (count($pieces) == 2) ? $pieces[1] : $pieces[1] . "." . $pieces[2]; 
    $server .= ".whois-servers.net"; 
    $fp = fsockopen($server, 43, $errno, $errstr, 10); 
    $result = ""; 
    if($fp === FALSE){ return FALSE; } 
    fputs($fp, $domain . "\r\n");     
    while(!feof($fp)){ $result .= fgets($fp, 128); } 
    fclose($fp); 

    return ((stristr($result, 'no match for') !== FALSE) || (strtolower($result) == "notfound\n")) ? TRUE : FALSE; 
}
```

Is there a way for this to work or is there a limit on whois-servers.net?

Comment: Whats the max_execution_time set to in PHP?  Secondly, check your error log for any relevant messages.  I'm not sure why it would 404, possibly how the web server is setup.

Comment: Consult each registry whois server instead of only one. And take into account their rate limiting and access policies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting 404 error 'cause the url in your code is wrong; change `whois-servers.net` to `whois-server.net`. Then, add a counter within the while loop and you'll get the limit. Otherwise, some say that the daily limit is 100 and others 1000 queries per ip.